# Magento - addCategoryFilter throws an error

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm successfully running this query:

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->setPage(1, 5);
```

but when I add

```
->addCategoryFilter('3')
```

I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/sitename/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php on line 556
```

The block it is running at is defined as

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.right.bestsellers" template="catalog/navigation/right.phtml"/>
```

at catalog.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This covers 1.4.2.  Based on your error, I think you're running a slightly older version, but the root cause of your error should be the same.

The class alias `reports/product_collection` resolves to

```
Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection
```

in resource mode context.   The class `Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection` is a child of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract`.  The `addCategoryFilter` on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract` looks like this

```
public function addCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
{
    $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] = $category->getId();
    if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
        unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);
    }
    else {
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1;
    }

    ($this->getStoreId() == 0)? $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations() : $this->_applyProductLimitations();

    return $this;
}
```

Notice that in 1.4.2 there's some type checking going on in the paramaters

```
public function addCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
```

I suspect your version doesn't have that checking.  Therefore, it fails when it reaches

```
$this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] = $category->getId();
```

You're passing in a string, and then Magento tries to call `getId` on the string.  That's why you get an error.

Magento expects you to pass in a **category object**, and not a category ID.  Give this a try

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$p = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->setPage(1, 5);
```

Comment: how can we get products from more than one category? this "addCategoryFilter()" will only take 1 category.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for [`addCategoryFilter()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#addCategoryFilter) must be an object of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`.